# Configuring HTTPS for Consul, gateway and microservice results in ZuulException: Forwarding error

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, jhipster, consul

### Situation

I implemented a JHipster microservice application with a microservice gateway, one microservice app and Consul for service discovery. It all works perfectly as long as I am using HTTP but considering use in production unencrypted connections are no viable option.

Therefore I modified all configuration files to use TLS/HTTPS like this:

#### Gateway/Microservice, application-tls.yml:

```
server:
    ssl:
        key-store: classpath:config/tls/keystore.jks
        key-store-type: JKS
        key-alias: selfsigned
        key-store-password: password
        ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
jhipster:
    http:
        version: V_2_0
spring:
    cloud:
        consul:
            discovery:
                scheme: https
```

Gateway and microservice TLS configurations are identical except for the contents of the keystore (they each have their own key pair).

### Problem

Consul and the two Spring Boot applications start without any errors and are registered correctly in Consul.

However, accessing the Gateway application via a web browser leads to the following error in the Gateway application:

#### GUI

```
Http failure response for https://localhost:8080/<MICROSERVICE-NAME>/api/<RESOURCE-NAME>: 500 OK
```

#### Stacktrace

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
...
at de.<MY-ORG>.<MY-PROJECT>.gateway.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
...
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: <MY-IP>:8081 failed to respond
```

8081 is the port of my microservice application.

As a result no APIs of the microservice are reachable and no functionalities (e.g. CRUD) can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Was using an older version of JHipster (5.8.2). An upgrade to 6.2.0 did the trick.